# How to totally disable elements events?

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I'm using the compound model and the cytoscape-compound-drag-and-drop extension to let the user manually reorganize the layout by grouping some nodes together and moving whole groups easily.

Now I want a button to toggle the display of these groups "boxes", but keep displaying all non-parent nodes.
I first tried hide() on parent nodes, but it also hides the children, so I switched to dynamically applying a class which specifies display:hidden.
It seemed to do the trick, **but still the hidden box can be clicked and cytoscape default "visual feedback" for click applies, showing off the area where the hidden box still lies.**

I tried plenty of things that didn't work:
 - [disable events from my hidden style class: tried events:no](https://js.cytoscape.org/#style/events). **Should I report this as a bug ?**
 - .ungrabify().unselectify().panify().lock()
 - on click: destroy the event object
 - set e.target._private.active = false

I tried a nasty hack: setting e.target._private.position = {} 
The event is still fired, but destroying the position **sucessfully prevents the "visual feedback" from happenning**, my box effectively stays "hidden".
But still the event occurs on the wrong target: the box, not on the empty space of the cytoscape container. I can keep hacking and leave with it, but isn't there a simpler solution to ?

**Is it possible to simply and truly pass through hidden parent nodes events ?**

Comment: event.preventDefault(); 
    event.stopPropagation(); 
    return false;

Comment: Hi, lhoro, thanks for the suggestion but I also tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: Hi Jeff, please provide us with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as described in [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). That way, we can try our solutions with your code to prevent guesses resulting in nothing.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't used `events` properly.

```js
cy.$('node').forEach(node => {
    node.events = 'no'; // will not work
});
```

The following does work, and you can also restore events whenever you want.

```js
cy.$('node').forEach(node => {
    node.style('events', 'no');
});
```