# Cytoscape.js: restore node events to 'yes' after setting it to 'no'

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I used solution from link below to prevent my nodes from catching mousedown event, so user can pan view by dragging at any place of screen including nodes.

[How to totally disable elements events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61276654/how-to-totally-disable-elements-events)

However, I'm not able to get `events` back to normal, when I choose selection tool in my app. I set `events` to 'yes', but nodes and edges still refuse to get selected. If I remove `node.style('events', 'no');`, elements will be selectable in selection mode, but also they will fire mousedown and so cause some troubles with panning view on them.

This code runs first when initiating the pan mode (default mode on start):

```
 this.cy.autoungrabify(true);
 this.cy.autounselectify(true);
 this.cy.userPanningEnabled(true);
 this.cy.$('node, edge').forEach(node => {
    node.style('events', 'no');//this works perfectly preventing elements from firing events
 });
```

Then if I choose selection mode (everything is vice versa):

```
 this.cy.autoungrabify(false);
 this.cy.autounselectify(false);
 this.cy.userPanningEnabled(false);
 this.cy.$('node, edge').forEach(node => {
    node.style('events', 'yes'); //but this takes no effect, elements remain unselectable.
    //property is actually set to 'yes', I checked it
 });
 ... setting some event listeners on nodes and edges ...
```

How can I revert `events` to normal?

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue, managed to fix it by adding the following afterwards:

```
this.cy.elements().remove().restore();
```